# Expanding JSON to flat file in M Code(Power Query) for Notion Dashboards

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery, notion-api

#### Disclaimer

I am looking for a way to flatten a JSON object in Mcode. However, I am also modest enough to know they may be a better way entirely. With that in mind, I have provided context and am open to the possibility that I am digging down the entirely wrong rabbit hole.

I know its a long question. I spent 4 hours preparing a test public database and cleaning up the code so it is as easy as possible for others to jump in and help. Thank you for taking the time

#### Background

I love Notion but it does lack powerful graphing tools. My workaround for this is manually exporting CSVs and using Excel and Power Query to transform the data before uploading it to [flourish.studio](https://flourish.studio/)

#### Overarching Goal

The goal is to have my data in notion, automatically updating beautiful diagrams that can then be embedded in Notion.
While not the main goal of this question I am also open to other solutions. (I have tried Google Looker Studio and was not impressed)

#### The current problem

Notion does allow for manual CSV export. However, this is manual.

Luckily they also have a powerful API. Unluckily it returns a deeply nested JSON object that Power Query really struggles to flatten into a useful CSV like structure.

#### Progress so far

1. Through research on stack overflow and trial and error, I have written some M-Code that when provided with a databaseId and APIKey grabs the JSON file and pulls it into Power Query.

   ```
   QueryDatabaseFromNotion(databaseId as text, apiSecretKey as text)
   ```
2. I have a custom function

   ```
   ConvertJSONBranchToCSV(DataTable as table, ColumnName as text)
   ```

   That converts most type of properties to their 'raw value'. There are 2 main limitations

   **Limitation 1:** SOLVED It must be applied individually to each column. I am now struggling to find a programmatic apply it to each column. (I have 6 databases, and each database has up to 80 columns)

   **Limitation 2:** I am not sure how to convert ONE-TO-MANY properties to a string with commas. (See section under "TYPE 4. COMPLEX:" comment in my code)

#### Summary of Questions

1. The ultimate goal is to get powerful diagraming into notion. Am I going down the wrong path with all of this?
2. Assuming this is a valid path and we should continue trying to bring notion nicely into power query, can you help me with **Limitations 1 and 2** above?

You can find my excel document all the code and sample database here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U_ImHIp3h83oXKZoupKb9BhnsTQDBAf2/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111108397944570955531&rtpof=true&sd=true
[image]

For those interested in quickly looking over my code I have included it below

```html
let 
    getRawValueFromJsonTree = (DataTable as table, ColumnName as text) =>
        let
            #"output" = 
                let 
                // =========== STEP 1. Dig one level deeper if property is 'rollup' or 'formula' =====================================================================================================================
                    // Columns which are 'rollup' or 'formula' can then be any other type.
                    // So this step is to dig one layer deep, so the rest of the code can run as normal.
                    // E.g. For 'number' properities                            the path = results{0}.properties.Title Column Name.number     
                    // E.g  Form 'formula' properties that result in a number   the path = results{0}.properties.Title Column Name.formula.number
                    intialTypeStr = 
                        try 
                            // This assumes that the datatype of the first record is the same for all records.
                            // TODO This is not true for icon and cover.
                            Table.ExpandRecordColumn(DataTable, ColumnName, {"type"})[type]{0}
                        catch(err) => 
                            if err[Message] <> null then "Error: Already Raw Data" else "Pass(This is never shown)",
                            
                    typeStr = 
                        if intialTypeStr = "rollup" then
                            // Note that Rollup Calculations will all return nulls if your secretAPIKey does not also have access to that database
                            Table.ExpandRecordColumn(DataTable, ColumnName, {"rollup"})[rollup]{0}[type]
                        else if intialTypeStr = "formula" then
                            Table.ExpandRecordColumn(DataTable, ColumnName, {"formula"})[formula]{0}[type]                      
                        else if intialTypeStr = null then
                            "Error: No Type Property"
                        else
                            intialTypeStr,
                            
                    #"BaseLevel" =
                        if intialTypeStr = "formula" then
                            Table.ExpandRecordColumn(DataTable, ColumnName, {"formula"}, {ColumnName})
                        else if intialTypeStr = "rollup" then
                            Table.ExpandRecordColumn(DataTable, ColumnName, {"rollup"}, {ColumnName})
                        else
                           DataTable
                in
                // =========== STEP 2. Extract the 'Raw value' from the JSON tree ======================================================================================================================================
                    if typeStr = "Error: Already Raw Data" then
                    // =========== TYPE 1. EASY: Already raw data. No chage require   ==================================================================================================================================
                        #"BaseLevel" // Column is already a raw type. No changes required
                    else if typeStr =  "Error: No Type Property" then
                        // This occurs with properties that all databases have. E.g. "created_by" (Fun fact the are actually not stored under 'properties' in the JSON)
                        Table.ExpandRecordColumn(DataTable, ColumnName, {"id"}, {ColumnName})
                    // =========== TYPE 2. EASY: Retrieving the value of property types that are ONLY 1 LAYER DEEP  ====================================================================================================
                    // First lets get the easy wins. 
                    // E.g. For 'number' properities the path = results{0}.properties.Title Column Name.number
                    // E.g. For 'string' properities the path = results{0}.properties.Title Column Name.string
                    else if 
                        typeStr = "checkbox"
                        or typeStr = "boolean" // This seems to only happen when a formula results in a checkbox
                        or typeStr = "string"
                        or typeStr = "email"
                        or typeStr = "number"
                        or typeStr = "phone_number"
                        or typeStr = "url"
                        or typeStr = "created_time"
                        or typeStr = "last_edited_time"      
                        or typeStr = "database_id"                     
                    then
                        Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName})
                    // ELSE
                    // =========== TYPE 3. MEDIUM: Retrieving the value of property types that have UNIQUE PATHS =======================================================================================================
                    // Next we do the more complicated ones with multiple layers
                    // E.g. For 'title' properities the path = results{0}.properties.Title Column Name.title{0}.plain_text
                    else if typeStr = "title" then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"A", ColumnName),
                            #"C" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"B", ColumnName, {"plain_text"}, {ColumnName})            
                        in
                            #"C"
                    else if 
                        typeStr = "status"
                        or typeStr = "select"
                    then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"A", ColumnName, {"name"}, {ColumnName})
                        in
                            #"B"
                    else if typeStr = "unique_id" then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"A", ColumnName, {"number"}, {ColumnName})
                        in
                            #"B"
                    else if typeStr = "rich_text" then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"A", ColumnName),
                            #"C" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"B", ColumnName, {"plain_text"}, {ColumnName})
                        in
                            #"C"
                    else if typeStr = "date" then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"START" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"A", ColumnName, {"start"}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"END" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"A", ColumnName, {"end"}, {ColumnName}),
                            // TODO Note that if start or end does not include time, then the date is not in the standard format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.mmmm+{timezone offset}
                            //#"B" = Text.Combine({Text.From(#"START"), Text.From(#"END")}, " to ") // TODO I am currently just ignoring END 
                            #"B" = #"START"                            
                        in
                            #"B"
                    else if 
                        typeStr = "created_by" 
                        or typeStr = "last_edited_by"
                    then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"A", ColumnName, {"id"}, {ColumnName})
                        in
                            #"B"
                    // =========== TYPE 4. COMPLEX: Retrieving the value of property types that are ONE-TO-MANY =========================================================================================================
                    else if typeStr = "array" then
                        // TRODO: Clean this up, Rollups with arrays can have confusing paths. Overlap with "title" property type above
                        // results{0}.properties.Title Column Name.rollup.array.{[{List_Object!}]}.title}.{[{List_Object!}]}.plain_text
                        // results{0}.properties.Title Column Name.rollup.array.{[{List_Object!}]}.{GetType()}.{[{List_Object!}]}.plain_text
                        // results{0}.properties.Title Column Name.rollup.array.{[{List_Object!}]}.{GetType()}.{[{List_Object!}]}.{GetType()}.content

                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"A", ColumnName),     // NOT USED. This creates multuple lines and that is bad.
                            //#"C" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"B", ColumnName, {"id"}, {ColumnName})
                            //#"C" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"B", ColumnName, {"plain_text"}, {ColumnName})
                            rollupTypeStr = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"B", ColumnName, {"type"}){0}[type],
                            #"DigBasedOnRollupType" =  if rollupTypeStr = "title" then
                                // For Rollup type = show_original
                                let 
                                    #"W" = #"B",
                                    #"X" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"W", ColumnName, {rollupTypeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                                    #"Y" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"X", ColumnName),      // NOT USED. This creates multuple lines and that is bad.
                                    #"Z" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Y", ColumnName, {"plain_text"}, {ColumnName})            
                                in
                                    //#"Z"
                                    #"X"
                            else if rollupTypeStr = null then 
                                // For Rollups Type = Sum
                                Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"B", ColumnName, {"id"}, {ColumnName})
                            else
                                //#"B"
                                rollupTypeStr
                        in                            
                            //#"DigBasedOnRollupType"
                            #"A"
                    else if typeStr = "relation" then
                        // TODO: this has the 'has_more' property. I suspect this means there is some pagination that needs to be included in the future when there are more then 100 relations. - And I know there will be ;( 
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"A", ColumnName),     // NOT USED. This creates multuple lines and that is bad.
                            #"C" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"B", ColumnName, {"id"}, {ColumnName})
                        in
                            //#"C"
                            #"A"
                    else if typeStr = "files" then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"A", ColumnName)     // NOT USED. This creates multuple lines and that is bad.
                        in
                            #"A"
                    else if typeStr = "multi_select" then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"A", ColumnName)     // NOT USED. This creates multuple lines and that is bad.
                        in
                            #"A"
                    else if typeStr = "relation" then
                        #"BaseLevel" // I havent had any luck yet
                    else if typeStr = "people" then
                        let 
                            #"A" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"BaseLevel", ColumnName, {typeStr}, {ColumnName}),
                            #"B" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"A", ColumnName)     // NOT USED. This creates multuple lines and that is bad.
                        in
                            #"A"
                    else
                        #"BaseLevel" // TODO: If a column type is not recognised then I should show a error to the user. But not break everything
            in
                #"output"
    in 
        getRawValueFromJsonTree
```

You can take a look at the JSON object returned by querying a notion database here: [JSON returned from Notion API](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rgr6q-dEp55d58qdxaHWPvgVZKUsAoZP/view?usp=sharing):

Comment: What does the JSON look like?  And wat is your target schema?

Comment: Good idea, I have added a link to an example JSON file to the original post. You can also find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rgr6q-dEp55d58qdxaHWPvgVZKUsAoZP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Pretty sure it is not http://flurish.com  Maybe https://flourish.studio/ ?

Comment: You are correct. I have updated that in the initial post

Answer (score 1):

With regard to **Limitation 1**, you can use `List.Accumulate` to cycle through the relevant columns.

- Create a List of the columns to convert

  - Many ways to do this
  - I just excluded the last column in your `#"Removed other columns` step
- Then use `List.Accumulate` as shown below

```
let
    Source = #"Get Notion Database in JSON",
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,
        {"Person ColumnName", "Relations ColumnName", "Rollup Sum ColumnName", "Date ColumnName", "Formula Boolean ColumnName", "Formula Number ColumnName", "Email ColumnName", "Sequential ID ColumnName", "Status ColumnName", "Rollup Original ColumnName", "Checkbox ColumnName", "Formula Text ColumnName", "Created by ColumnName", "Multi-select ColumnName", "Formula Date ColumnName", "Last edited time ColumnName", "Number ColumnName", "Select ColumnName", "Phone ColumnName", "URL ColumnName", "Files & media ColumnName", "Rollup Latest Date ColumnName", "Text ColumnName", "Rollup Count ColumnName", "Created time ColumnName", "Last edited by ColumnName", "Title ColumnName", "url"}),

//create list of columns to convert
    #"Convert Columns" = List.RemoveLastN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Other Columns"),1),

//expand all of those columns using List.Accumulate
    #"Convert JSON" = 
        List.Accumulate(
            #"Convert Columns",
            #"Removed Other Columns",
            (state, current) => ConvertJSONBranchToCSV(state, current))
in 
    #"Convert JSON"
```

Comment: Excellent, that solves limitation 1.
I have updated the excel sheet with you code. 

I also updated ConvertJSONBranchToCSV() so it no longer breaks on the last column. (And so removed List.RemoveLastN()))